# Can't understand Bayes theorem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

A software company conducted a test on their new platform by exposing their users to two versions of the same product.

Number of users that were given version A: 4000

Number of user that were given version B: 5000

Number of users that experienced a bug: 3000

Number of users with version B that experienced a bug: 1500

What is the probability that a user tested Version B, given they experienced a bug during testing?

---

**My attempt**

I don’t get this question at all.

Let X = user tested Version B
Let Y = experienced a bug during testing

$P(X|Y)=P(X \cap Y)/P(Y)$

$P(X \cap Y) = P(X) \cdot P(Y|X) = \dfrac{5000}{9000} \times \dfrac{1500}{3000} = \dfrac{5}{18}$

$P(Y) = P(X).P(Y|X) + P(X^c).P(Y|X^c)$

Now how do we go from here? and is the probability calculated above correct? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, except for one mistake.

$$P(Y|X) = \frac{1500}{5000} = \frac{3}{10}$$

The denominator will be $5000$ because it's the probability of a user experiencing a bug if they had version B. How many had version B? $5000$, right. How many of those experienced a bug? $1500$. See why it should be $5000$ and not $3000$?

Similarly $P(X^c) = \dfrac{4000}{9000}$ and $P(Y|X^c) = \dfrac{1500}{4000}$.

I believe you can take it from here. Just plug the values into your formula.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. Your solution leads to the correct answer. The part that I am still struggling with is, how was it concluded that number of users who experienced bug while testing version A was also 1500? Please help me with this, since the problem description never mentions that clearly.

Comment: @MusabGulfam The total number of users who experienced a bug is $3000$. $1500$ of these are users with version B. So the remaining [$3000 - 1500 = 1500$] must be the users who had version A and experienced a bug. Makes sense?

Comment: Also, if this post answered your question, please consider accepting it (the check mark by the side). Not only does it help the author but also the algorithm and others who might have a similar problem and come to this page. One glance and they can spot the accepted answer.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.